# Tentativa de manipular valores de um vetor gerado por um JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array, react-native

Estou tentando "alterar" valores de um vetor recebido a partir do consumo de um JSON.
Minha lógica foi criar um `for` para percorrer o vetor, analisar o item naquela partição e reescrever em um vetor cópia, tendo assim um vetor com os valores que eu desejo.

```
    let copia = [];

for(i = 0; i< data.day.lenght; i++){     
  switch(data.day[i]){
    case 'Mon':
      copia[i] = 'Segunda';
    default:
      copia[i] = 'Não'
  }
}

return(   
   <Text style = {styles.welcome}>Day: {copia}</Text>)
```

O problema é que o meu vetor cópia está saindo em branco sempre. O que vocês acham?

Comment: Tem como postar a saída JSON para análise da estrutura?

Answer (score 0):

Faz aassim:

```
var vetor = [];
var obj = JSON.parse(objetoJSON);

for (i in obj){
// condição if
vetor[i] = obj[i].nomeDaPropriedadeNoObjetoJson (exemplo: obj[i].nome)
// elseif
vetor[i] = obj[i].nomeDaPropriedadeNoObjetoJson (exemplo: obj[i].email)
}
```

Não sei bem se é isso.
Especifique melhor a sua dúvida.
Att.

Answer (score 0):

A meu ver o problema está no seu Json. O `data.day.lenght` está vindo zerado porque, se passasse uma vez ali, o seu vetor `copia` teria dado.

Tenta usar `console.log(data.day);` e `console.log(data.day.length);` antes do `for` para ver a consistência do dado.

Answer (score 0):

Se o `copia` é uma array, você deveria expor no JSX para que seja concatenao como string, uma boa maneira de fazer isso é com o [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
<Text style = {styles.welcome}>Day: {...copia}</Text>)
```

Outro approach é iterar em `copia`, transfornado-a em nós de JSX:

```
let copia = [];

for(i = 0; i< data.day.lenght; i++){     
  switch(data.day[i]){
    case 'Mon':
      copia[i] = 'Segunda';
    default:
      copia[i] = 'Não'
  }
}
let copiaNodes=copia.map((copiaItem) => {
   return <Text style = {styles.welcome}>Day: {copiaItem}</Text>
});

return (<View>{copiaNodes}</View>);
```

Se persistir os sintomas, você pode debugar e ver se copia está sendo populado.

Boa sorte!